# Position:relative/absolute not working the way I'd like in Dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, sass

Hey I'm trying to create a dropdown menu on my website, however, when I put the parent "relative" and child "absolute", the dropdown menu gets covered by (goes below) the next element (which is Header). But if I remove "relative" from the parent, it doesn't get covered but then the positioning isn't right.

Below is the code for both the menu AND the next element (since i'm not sure whether it's the problem from the menu or from the header).

HTML

```
    <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="nav-header">
    <div class="container">
      <nav id="main-nav">
        <img src="./project_resources/img/logoTommy2.png" alt="my Portfolio" id="logo">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about-a">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="projects.html" target="_blank">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact-a">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html" class="current">EN</a></li>
              <li><a href="french.html">FR</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>  
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="header-home">
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="container">
        <h1><span class="first-a">T</span>ommy <span class="first-a">L</span>ing <br> Web Developer</h1>
        <p class="header-subtitle">Rotman MBA Grad</p>
        <p class="header-subtitle">Lighthouse Labs</p>
        <a href="https://github.com/tommy-ling/my_portfolio" class="btn-light" target="_blank">See My Github For This Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

CSS

```
// General Styles
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: #fff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  // color: $dark-color;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

h2,
h3,
h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.first-a {
  color: $main-color;
}

// Logo
#logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 120px;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

// Nav-Header
.nav-header {
  background-color: $dark-color;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 10;
}

// Main Nav
#main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  li {
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  }
  a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 3px transparent solid;
    transition: border-color 0.5s;
    &:hover {
      border-color: $medium-color;
    }
    &.current {
      border-color: $main-color;
    }
  }

  // Nested Language Section
  ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;

    ul {
      display: none;
    }

    &:hover ul {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 8.5px;
      width: 3rem;
      // margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    &:hover ul li {
      display: block;
      background: $light-color;

      a {
        color: $dark-color;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Header
#header {
  &-home {
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: $bg-color;
  }
}

// Header Content
.header-content {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 8%;

  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 100;
  }

  .header-subtitle {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 1.7rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that position absolute removes elements from normal flow...

Comment: Hey thanks. Right, however, I did put position relative into the parent element. Strangely, after doing so, the element with absolute position goes below the next element (the header)

Comment: Try adding positioning to your header; that often works when working with z-index

Comment: Hmm positioning meaning adding position: absolute/relative to the header? Didn't work :/